# Retrieve the final value in a Map

Tags: java, collections

Given the following String data:

```
"1:1000,6:5000,12:15000"
```

and the following code:

```
 public Map<String, String> getCommaSeperatedSalaryMap(String salaries) {
        if (salaries.isEmpty()) {
            return Maps.newHashMap();
        }
        Map<String, String> salariesList = Arrays.stream(salaries.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].trim(), s -> s[1].trim()));

        return salariesList;
    }
```

...which returns my map in k/v format as expected:

```
key: 1, value: 1000
key: 6, value: 5000
key: 12, value:15000
```

...I want to retrieve the final value in the Map.  So in this case, a method that returns `15000`. I think I can use `entrySet()`...I'm sure it's staring me in the face - just Monday mental block :(

Comment: ´map_dict.values()[-1]´ ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to retrieve "_the final value in the Map_"? The last one you inserted?

Comment: @maloomeister so I'm passing the String "1:1000,6:5000,12:15000" and I want to retrieve 15000.  Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding

Comment: @Steerpike the default Map implementation used by `Collectors.toMap()` does not maintain insertion order, it is an unordered `HashMap`. To maintain insertion order, you need a different Map implementation, e.g. a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Thank you @Hulk ~ I'm a tester and I don't code all the time so sometimes need reminders! LinkedHashMap looks to be what I need.

Comment: `salaries.substring(salaries.lastIndexOf(':') + 1)`?

Comment: @Steerpike you should probably don't use streams at all, the solution suggested by Holger should be exactly what you need. Though you may need to ensure that `salaries.lastIndexOf(':') >= 0`

Comment: You never defined “last”. The most recently added entry? The value with the greatest number? The value assigned to the greatest key number?

Comment: Calling your map a “List” is confusing. A list and a map are two different data structures in the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about an arbitrary `Map`, then what you are trying to do is not possible. A `Map` is a mapping from an unordered (or undefined order) set of keys to values. It is not possible to know which value was added last without storing it separetely or writing your own `Map` implementation that keeps track of this order.

That being said, what you can do is store the data in a `List` instead. Creating a `List<SalaryData>` and a `SalaryData` class that stores what currently is the key and the value, you can add all entries there without losing the order in which you've added them. Additionally, if you are doing many lookups by key, you can still keep a parallel `Map` for efficient access to the data.